# puzzled about document.documentElement

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom

I  got puzzled about it .
1 Is document equal to document.documentElement? I think they are both root node.
2 Why I can use document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName() but I can not use 
document.documentElement.getElementById()?

Comment: Open up the developer console, look at the result of both `document` and `document.documentElement`. How does it differ? I would link to the appropriate MDN documentation, but it appears to currently be down; and such questions about API can be self-resolved.

Comment: Why would it reference itself? That wouldn't make much sense

Comment: The document has two  lines additional :
#document
<!DOCTYPE>

I still can not catch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the document *object* and the document *element.*

When an HTML document is loaded into a web browser, it becomes a document object.

The document object is the root node of the HTML document and the common ancestor of all other nodes, such as element nodes (including the document element), text nodes and attribute nodes.

One of the differences is that an *element* [has `getElementsByTagName()` but *not* `getElementById()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp), which is part of the [document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) itself.

To successfully use an element to get another one based on ID, you need to go *through* its document:

```
var elem2 = elem1.ownerDocument.getElementById(whatever)
```

Comment: Wrt being the "common ancestor", for a standard page there is this relation: `document.children === [document.documentElement]` (where documentElement is the "html node").

Comment: Now I GOT this question:<br/>
document.getElementsByTagName("svg")<br/>
returns  a array whose length is one (first child is not undefined)<br/>
but when I change it to document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0],it returns undefined.
<br/>
The svg has been  created by javascript.I do not why.

Comment: @张绍峰, you should ask that as a *question.* If you ask it here, I'm pretty much the only one who gets notified. New questions, *everyone* will see.